# Yii2 paypal payment integration

Tags: php, paypal, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using this https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bitcko/yii2-bitcko-paypal-api#usage With yii2 to enable payments my code looks like this.

```
public function actionMakePayment(){
          if(!Yii::$app->user->getIsGuest()){
               // Setup order information array
              $params = [
                  'order'=>[
                      'description'=>'Payment description',
                      'subtotal'=>45,
                      'shippingCost'=>0,
                      'total'=>45,
                      'currency'=>'USD',
                  ]
              ];
            // In case of payment success this will return the payment object that contains all information about the order
            // In case of failure it will return Null

            Yii::$app->PayPalRestApi->processPayment($params);
        }else{
          Yii::$app->response->redirect(Url::to(['site/signup'], true));
        }
```

Everything is went as per my expectation this call is returning somthing like this to dom.

```
{ "id": "PAYID-LTKUAVA8WK14445NN137182H", "intent": "sale", "state": "approved", "cart": "9RE74926AX5730813", "payer": { "payment_method": "paypal", "status": "UNVERIFIED", "payer_info": { "first_name": "Susi", "last_name": "Flo", "payer_id": "KWPDGYRP2KCK4", "shipping_address": { "recipient_name": "Susi Flo", "line1": "Suso", "line2": "bldg", "city": "Spring hill", "state": "FL", "postal_code": "34604", "country_code": "US" }, "phone": "3526003902", "country_code": "US" } }, "transactions": [ { "amount": { "total": "45.00", "currency": "USD", "details": { "subtotal": "45.00", "shipping": "0.00", "insurance": "0.00", "handling_fee": "0.00", "shipping_discount": "0.00" } }, "payee": { "merchant_id": "NHN6S6KT4FF6N", "email": "arunwebber2-facilitator@gmail.com" }, "description": "Payment description", "invoice_number": "5cd5404d624a9", "soft_descriptor": "PAYPAL *TESTFACILIT", "item_list": { "items": [ { "name": "Item one", "price": "45.00", "currency": "USD", "tax": "0.00", "quantity": 1 } ], "shipping_address": { "recipient_name": "Susi Flo", "line1": "Suso", "line2": "bldg", "city": "Spring hill", "state": "FL", "postal_code": "34604", "country_code": "US" } }, "related_resources": [ { "sale": { "id": "6LN25215GP1183020", "state": "completed", "amount": { "total": "45.00", "currency": "USD", "details": { "subtotal": "45.00", "shipping": "0.00", "insurance": "0.00", "handling_fee": "0.00", "shipping_discount": "0.00" } }, "payment_mode": "INSTANT_TRANSFER", "protection_eligibility": "ELIGIBLE", "protection_eligibility_type": "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE,UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE", "transaction_fee": { "value": "2.43", "currency": "USD" }, "receipt_id": "3896118010137330", "parent_payment": "PAYID-LTKUAVA8WK14445NN137182H", "create_time": "2019-05-10T09:30:10Z", "update_time": "2019-05-10T09:30:10Z", "links": [ { "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/6LN25215GP1183020", "rel": "self", "method": "GET" }, { "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/6LN25215GP1183020/refund", "rel": "refund", "method": "POST" }, { "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LTKUAVA8WK14445NN137182H", "rel": "parent_payment", "method": "GET" } ], "soft_descriptor": "PAYPAL *TESTFACILIT" } } ] } ], "create_time": "2019-05-10T09:11:48Z", "update_time": "2019-05-10T09:30:10Z", "links": [ { "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LTKUAVA8WK14445NN137182H", "rel": "self", "method": "GET" } ] }
```

How can I store this to my database? for a specefi user id i can get user id with this.

```
echo Yii::$app->user->id;
```

I want to store this value along with the user id how can I do that? And a payment success message to the user :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Looks like the component class needs to be fully copied and edited before it can correctly override the `checkOut()` method as the property `$apiContext` accessed in the method is `private` rather than being `$protected` so either you copy that whole component and place it in you `frontend/components` directory and change it accordingly and then use.

Above all that class is poorly designed and written too, it would be better if you use the following component that i have been using in my Yii2 projects. I havent removed the extra code and have pasted the file as is in the answer. you can remove/comment the part related to the `BalanceHistory` `TransactionHistory` and the email part. you need to install paypal checkout sdk via composer or add below in your `composer.json`

`"paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk": "1.0.1"`

Paypal Component

```
<?php

namespace frontend\components;

use Yii;
use common\models\{
    User,
    BalanceHistory,
    TransactionHistory
};
use yii\base\Component;
use common\components\Helper;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\{
    PayPalHttpClient,
    SandboxEnvironment,
    ProductionEnvironment
};
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\{
    OrdersGetRequest,
    OrdersCreateRequest,
    OrdersCaptureRequest
};

class Paypal extends Component
{

    /**
     * The Pyapal Client Id
     *
     * @var mixed
     */
    public $clientId;

    /**
     * The Paypal client Secret
     *
     * @var mixed
     */
    public $clientSecret;

    /**
     * API context object
     *
     * @var mixed
     */
    private $httpClient; // paypal's http client

    /**
     * @var mixed
     */
    private $user_id;

    /**
     * Override Yii's object init()
     *
     * @return null
     */
    public function init()
    {
        $this->httpClient = new PayPalHttpClient(
            Yii::$app->params['paypal']['mode'] == 'sandbox' ?
                new SandboxEnvironment($this->clientId, $this->clientSecret) :
                new ProductionEnvironment($this->clientId, $this->clientSecret)
        );

        $this->user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;

        Yii::info("User: {$this->user_id} Init PayPal", 'paypal');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the context object
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->httpClient;
    }

    /**
     * Set the payment methods and other objects necessary for making the payment
     *
     * @param decimal $price the amount to be charged
     *
     * @return string $approvalUrl
     */
    public function createOrder($price)
    {
        //create order request
        $request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
        $request->prefer('return=representation');

        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US.UTF-8');

        $price = sprintf('%01.2f', $price);

        Yii::info("User: {$this->user_id} Setting payment for amount: {$price}", 'paypal');

        //build the request body
        $requestBody = [
            'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
            'purchase_units' =>
            [
                0 =>
                [
                    'amount' =>
                    [
                        'currency_code' => 'USD',
                        'value' => $price,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'application_context' => [
                'shipping_preference' => 'NO_SHIPPING'
            ]
        ];

        $request->body = $requestBody;

        //call PayPal to set up a transaction
        $client = $this->getClient();
        $response = $client->execute($request);

        return json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }

    /**
     * @param $orderId
     */
    public function getOrder($orderId)
    {

        // 3. Call PayPal to get the transaction details
        $request = new OrdersGetRequest($orderId);
        $client = $this->getClient();
        $response = $client->execute($request);

        return json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves Order Capture Details for the given order ID
     *
     * @param string $orderId the payment id of the transaction
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function captureOrder($orderId)
    {
        $request = new OrdersCaptureRequest($orderId);
        //Call PayPal to capture an authorization
        $client = $this->getClient();

        $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
        try {
            $response = $client->execute($request);

            //get payment variables for email
            $paymentId = $response->result->id;
            $paymentStatus = $response->result->status;
            $paypalTransaction = $response->result->purchase_units[0]->payments->captures[0];
            $payedAmount = $paypalTransaction->amount->value;
            $txnId = $paypalTransaction->id;
            $userId = $this->user_id;

            //get the user
            $model = User::findOne($userId);
            $profile = $model->businessProfile;
            $prevBalance = $profile->balance;

            if ($paymentStatus == 'COMPLETED') {
                Yii::info("User: {$userId} payment amount:{$payedAmount} approved updating balance.", 'paypal');
                //update balance
                $newBalance = $profile->updateBalance($payedAmount);

                Yii::info("User: {$userId} balance updated.", 'paypal');

                $data = [
                    'amount' => $payedAmount,
                    'type' => TransactionHistory::BALANCE_ADDED,
                    'description' => "Funds added to account",
                    'user' => [
                        'id' => $userId,
                        'balance' => $newBalance,
                    ],
                ];

                Yii::info("User: {$userId} adding transaction history.", 'paypal');

                TransactionHistory::add($data);

                //update subscription status if required
                if ($profile->subscription_status !== 'active') {
                    $profile->updateStatus('active');
                }

                Yii::info("User: {$userId} adding balance history:{$payedAmount}.", 'paypal');

                //send the success email to the user and admin
                $this->sendNotification($model, $response->result);

                //set session flash with success
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash(
                    'success',
                    'Your Payment is processed and you will receive an email with the details shortly'
                );
            } else {
                Yii::warning("User: {$userId} payment amount:{$payedAmount} NOT approved.", 'paypal');
                //send the error email to the user and admin

                $this->sendNotification($model, $response->result, 'error');
                //set session flash with error
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash(
                    'danger',
                    'Your Payment was not approved, an email has been sent with the details.'
                );
            }

            //update balance history
            BalanceHistory::add(
                $profile->user_id,
                $prevBalance,
                $payedAmount,
                $paymentId,
                $paymentStatus,
                $txnId,
                $response
            );

            //commit the transaction
            $transaction->commit();

            Yii::info(
                "User: {$userId} payment Success prevBalance: {$prevBalance} payedAmount:{$payedAmount}.",
                'paypal'
            );
            return json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            //roll back the transaction
            $transaction->rollBack();

            Yii::error("ERROR EXCEPTION", 'paypal');
            Yii::error($e->getMessage(), 'paypal');
            Yii::error($e->getTraceAsString(), 'paypal');

            //send error email to the developers
            Helper::sendExceptionEmail(
                "TC : Exception on PayPal Balance",
                $e->getMessage(),
                $e->getTraceAsString()
            );

            //set session flash with error
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('danger', $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sends Success Email for the transaction
     *
     * @param \common\models\User $model the user model object
     * @param  $response the paypal Order Capture object
     * @param string $type the type of the notification to be sent
     *
     * @return null
     */
    public function sendNotification(
        \common\models\User $model,
        $response,
        $type = 'success'
    ) {
        Yii::info("User: {$this->user_id} Sending notifications type:{$type}", 'paypal');

        $paymentId = $response->id;
        $paymentStatus = $response->status;
        $paypalTransaction = $response->purchase_units[0]->payments->captures[0];
        $payedAmount = $paypalTransaction->amount->value;

        //payment creation time
        $paymentCreateTime = new \DateTime(
            $paypalTransaction->create_time,
            new \DateTimeZone('UTC')
        );

        //payment update time
        $paymentUpdateTime = new \DateTime(
            $paypalTransaction->update_time,
            new \DateTimeZone('UTC')
        );

        //payer/billing info for email
        $payerInfo = $response->payer;
        $payerEmail = $payerInfo->email_address;
        $payerFirstName = $payerInfo->name->given_name;
        $payerLastName = $payerInfo->name->surname;
        $billingInfo = [
            'billing_info' => [
                'email' => $payerEmail,
                'full_name' => "$payerFirstName $payerLastName",
            ],
        ];

        if (property_exists($response->purchase_units[0], 'shipping')) {
            $payerAddress = property_exists($response->purchase_units[0]->shipping->address, 'address_line_1');
            $isStateAvailable = property_exists($response->purchase_units[0]->shipping->address, 'admin_area_1');
            $isPostCodeAvailable = property_exists($response->purchase_units[0]->shipping->address, 'postal_code');
            $iscountryCodeAvailable = property_exists($response->purchase_units[0]->shipping->address, 'country_code');
            //@codingStandardsIgnoreStart
            $payerState =  $isStateAvailable ? $response->purchase_units[0]->shipping->address->admin_area_1 : 'NA';
            $payerPostalCode = $isPostCodeAvailable ? $response->purchase_units[0]->shipping->address->postal_code : 'NA';
            $payerCountryCode = $iscountryCodeAvailable ? $response->purchase_units[0]->shipping->address->country_code : 'NA';
            //@codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
            $billingInfo['billing_info'] = array_merge(
                $billingInfo['billing_info'],
                [
                    'address' => $payerAddress,
                    'state' => $payerState,
                    'country' => $payerCountryCode,
                    'post_code' => $payerPostalCode,
                ]
            );
        }

        //email params
        $data = [
            'user' => [
                'email' => $model->email,
                'name' => $model->username,
            ],
            'payment_id' => $paymentId,
            'amount' => $payedAmount,
            'status' => $paymentStatus,
            'create_time_utc' => $paymentCreateTime,
            'update_time_utc' => $paymentUpdateTime,
        ];

        $data = array_merge($data, $billingInfo);

        //check the notification email type and set params accordingly
        if ($type == 'success') {
            $txnId = $paypalTransaction->id;
            $data['txn_id'] = $txnId;
            $subject = Yii::$app->id . ': Your Account has been recharged.';
            $view = '@frontend/views/user/mail/payment-complete';
        } else {
            $subject = Yii::$app->id . ': Transaction failed.';
            $view = '@frontend/views/user/mail/payment-failed';
        }

        Yii::info("User: {$this->user_id} Sending email to user:{$model->email} type: {$type}", 'paypal');
        //send email to user
        $model->sendEmail($subject, $view, $data, $model->email);

        //send notification to admin for Payment Received
        $data['user']['email'] = Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'];

        $subject = ($type == 'success') ?
            Yii::$app->id . ': New Transaction in Account.' :
            Yii::$app->user->id . ': A Transaction Failed for the user.';

        Yii::info(
            "User: {$this->user_id} Sending email to admin " . Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'] . " type: {$type}",
            'paypal'
        );
        //send admin email
        $model->sendEmail($subject, $view, $data, Yii::$app->params['adminEmail']);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

You can call `createOrder` and then the `captureOrder` respectively. I was using it with ajax approach so i had separate actions defined like below

```
/**
     * Displays fail message to the user
     *
     * @param string $token the cancel token
     *
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function actionPaymentCancel($token)
    {
        Yii::warning("Payment Cancel : token: {$token}.", 'paypal');

        return $this->render(
            'payment-cancelled',
            [
                'data' => $token,
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Shows the payment details & success message to the user
     *
     * @param string $paymentId the payment id
     *
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function actionPaymentComplete($paymentId)
    {
        $history = BalanceHistory::findOne(['payment_id' => $paymentId]);

        return $this->render(
            'payment-complete',
            [
                'data' => $history,
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Captures the Paypal order and verifies it
     *
     * @param string $orderId the Paypal order object's id
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCaptureOrder($orderId)
    {
        $orderInfo = Yii::$app->paypal->captureOrder($orderId);
        return $orderInfo;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the order and
     *
     * @param string $amount the price of the order
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreateOrder($amount)
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            $order = Yii::$app->paypal->createOrder($amount);
            return $order;
        }
        throw new Exception("You are not logged in.", 404);
    }

    /**
     * Executes the payement and checkouts to the paypal to confirm
     *
     * @param string $token     the paypal token
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionPaymentExecute($orderId)
    {
        //get transaction details
        $details = Yii::$app->paypal->getOrder($orderId);

        $details = json_decode($details);

        //added check for duplicate hits to return url from Paypal
        if (null !== BalanceHistory::transactionExists($orderId)) {
            //redirect to payment complete
            return $this->redirect(['payment-complete', 'paymentId' => $orderId]);
        }

        if ($details->status == 'COMPLETED') {
            //redirect to payment complete
            return $this->redirect(['payment-complete', 'paymentId' => $orderId]);
        } else {
            //redirect to the payment failed page
            return $this->redirect(['payment-failed', 'paymentId' => $orderId]);
        }
    }
```

ALso keep in mind that you need to declare a param with live and local ENV for the paypal gateway which turns sandbox environment ON/OFF.

`params-local.php`

```
<?php
    'paypal'=>[
        'sandbox'=>true
    ]
?>
```

`params.php`

```
<?php
    'paypal'=>[
        'sandbox'=>false
    ]
?>
```

---

Paypal PHP-SDK Provides you the [`setCustom()`](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/CartBase.php#L153) to add a custom field value, you can use it to send the user id and then retrieve it with the response in the transaction object after the payment is executed.

What you are using is just a custom component using the Paypal SDK functions,you should extend the class `bitcko\paypalrestapi\PayPalRestApi.php` to override the function `checkOut()` and add the `->setCustom(Yii::$app->user->id)` to the chain in this [line](https://github.com/bitcko/yii2-bitcko-paypal-api/blob/master/PayPalRestApi.php#L68), as it does not provide any way to set the custom field, so just copy the whole code of the method into your new class and add the above.

Your class should look like below.

**NOTE: Add the file inside `common/components` folder.**

```
<?php
namespace common\components;

use bitcko\paypalrestapi\PayPalRestApi as PayPalBase;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use Yii;

class PaypalRestApi extends PayPalBase
{

    public function checkOut($params)
    {
        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod($params['method']);
        $orderList = [];

        foreach ($params['order']['items'] as $orderItem) {
            $item = new Item();
            $item->setName($orderItem['name'])
                ->setCurrency($orderItem['currency'])
                ->setQuantity($orderItem['quantity'])
                ->setPrice($orderItem['price']);
            $orderList[] = $item;
        }
        $itemList = new ItemList();
        $itemList->setItems($orderList);
        $details = new Details();
        $details->setShipping($params['order']['shippingCost'])
            ->setSubtotal($params['order']['subtotal']);
        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency($params['order']['currency'])
            ->setTotal($params['order']['total'])
            ->setDetails($details);
        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($itemList)
            ->setDescription($params['order']['description'])
            ->setCustom(Yii::$app->user->id)
            ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

        $redirectUrl = Url::to([$this->redirectUrl], true);
        $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("$redirectUrl?success=true")
            ->setCancelUrl("$redirectUrl?success=false");
        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent($params['intent'])
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
            ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
        try {
            $payment->create($this->apiContext);
            return \Yii::$app->controller->redirect($payment->getApprovalLink());
        } catch (PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
            // This will print the detailed information on the exception.
            //REALLY HELPFUL FOR DEBUGGING
            \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_HTML;
            \Yii::$app->response->data = $ex->getData();
        }
    }
}
```

Now change your configurations for the `PayPalRestApi` component class in the `common/config/main.php` or `frontend/config/main.php` whichever you are using, to the new class you created

```
'components'=> [
    ...
 'PayPalRestApi'=>[
      'class'=>'common\components\PayPalRestApi',
  ]
    ...
]
```

so now you can get the same user id by using

```
$response = \yii\helpers\Json::decode( Yii::$app->PayPalRestApi->processPayment($params));
$user_id = $response['transactions'][0]['custom'];
```

Comment: No i am using yii2 advanced

Comment: then change your namespaces accordingly @arunwebber from `app` to `common`, shouldnt be that hard i think, but anyway i have updated the code above.

Comment: I am getting null over here   $response = \yii\helpers\Json::decode( Yii::$app->PayPalRestApi->processPayment($params));
            var_dump($response);

Comment: that is odd we didnt changed anything in the `processPayment()`

Comment: https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/yii2-paypal-integration/126032 See this as well. Also if i use the module directly from the vendor also it showing me the same Aka showing null where as return shows the json on DOM

Comment: @arunwebber can you verify if it is going inside the `if(isset(Yii::$app->request->get()['success']) && Yii::$app->request->get()['success'] == 'true')` in the `processPayment($params)` function

Comment: Yeah, it is going inside

Comment: This code i working fine but if i use this for live I am getting this error too '{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}` Where as everything is working fine with the sandbox I have checked the doc they are saying to work on somthing like this. https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Adding-Configurations Is that the problem or somthing else? Any idea?

Comment: i also got the same response because i was working on my local system and PAYPal has some problem with asian coutries it does not allow you to use live mode when you are on local system, you should check the code by pushing on live domain it will work correctly @arunwebber , but you need to updaate the client id and secret for the live and add `mode=>live` to the configurations

Comment: How do you access $apiContext when it's a private property of the parent class?  If I try to declare it, I get an error when processPayment() is called:
Credential not found for default user. Please make sure your configuration/APIContext has credential information

Comment: @IBNets , we dont!, the class does that itself inside the constructor, we just set the `client_ID` and `client_SECRET` and those are fed to the `$apiContext` by the class, so go ahead and add those 2 inside the `params.php`  file `payPalClientId` and `payPalClientSecret`. see this line for more clarity https://github.com/bitcko/yii2-bitcko-paypal-api/blob/master/PayPalRestApi.php#L27

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Thanks for your reply!  I do have the credentials stored in params.php. And I can make calls to the api.  The problem is that $this->apiContext is used in your override PayPalRestApi class shown above, and that is throwing an error for me because it's a private property of the parent class (PayPalBase).

Comment: @IBNets seriously speaking that is a poorly designed and coded , and i would hardly use that , i have updated my answer with the component that I have used to configure paypal.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam That's what I was thinking.  I ended up copying the whole thing over.  But I'll switch to your component.  Thank you much for sharing that.

Comment: @IBNets no problem, infact  its good that you highlighted it as the answer was vague and not an actual answer to the problem, now at least it helps the cause.